# RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition on small distance is too fast

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In our chat app we use RecyclerView that can have messages with different heights. I want to animate message add with smoothScroll. My problem is: when I use `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)` on messages with small height, it scrolls too fast.

I also tried this [solution changing smoothScoll speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784136/2098878), its good for small messages, but when message is big its scroll speed making message appear too slow.

My perfect speed achieves with `recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(x, y)`, but here I have problem getting inserted message height, since messages can have any height.

Comment: extend `LinearSmoothScroller` and override `calculateSpeedPerPixel`

Comment: I already tried it. The speed on small items is good, but when I try big item, I got slow scroll speed.

Comment: oh, ok , i didnt check the link you posted...

Comment: I tried again that solution extending LinearSmoothScroller, and speed `MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 125f;`  was OK for me.  Thank you @pskink.

Answer (score 1):

Override `calculateTimeForScrolling` method of `LinearSmoothScroller` that calculate time for all distances:

```
public class SpeedyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private int smoothScrollDuration;

public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int smoothScrollDuration) {
    super(context);
    this.smoothScrollDuration = smoothScrollDuration;
}

public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout, int smoothScrollDuration) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.smoothScrollDuration = smoothScrollDuration;
}

public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes, int smoothScrollDuration) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.smoothScrollDuration = smoothScrollDuration;
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {

    final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {

        @Override
        protected int calculateTimeForScrolling(int dx) {
            return smoothScrollDuration;
        }
    };

    linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
}

public int getSmoothScrollDuration() {
    return smoothScrollDuration;
}

public void setSmoothScrollDuration(int smoothScrollDuration) {
    this.smoothScrollDuration = smoothScrollDuration;
}
}
```

And use it for recyclerview:

```
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(context, 100);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```