# Is there any way to "smooth scroll" a RecyclerView in a predetermined time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I would like to know if there is any native way to "smooth scroll" a `RecyclerView` in a predetermined time.

To exemplify my question, I would like that a vertical `RecyclerView`, with 10000dp height, scroll from the bottom to the top with the same amount of time that it would scroll from its middle (5000dp) to the top.

If interpolators were available to be used, it would be awesome :)

---

I couldn't find anything similar to `.scrollTo(pos: Int, interpolator: Interpolator, duration: Long)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241948/how-can-i-control-the-scrolling-speed-of-recyclerview-smoothscrolltopositionpos). Basically you should override `LinearSmoothScroller` behavior and implement your own logic in `calculateSpeedPerPixel` method (the name speaks for itself).