# Can "smoothScrollToPosition" speed be slowed in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to slow the scrolling speed of smoothScrollToPosition that i have used with listview.

I need to slow the list after a button click

here is an sample of my Code:

```
`Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            systemApsLv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            systemApsLv.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    systemApsLv.smoothScrollToPosition(systemApsLv.getCount()-1);
//                        systemApsLv.setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 1);
                                }
                            });}}`
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241948/how-can-i-control-the-scrolling-speed-of-recyclerview-smoothscrolltopositionpos

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i control the scrolling speed of recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241948/how-can-i-control-the-scrolling-speed-of-recyclerview-smoothscrolltopositionpos)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> position: up to where you want to scroll

```
val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
val smoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(context) {
        override fun getVerticalSnapPreference(): Int {
                return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_START
      }
}
smoothScroller.targetPosition=position
layoutManager.startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller)
```

Comment: What is val here?

Comment: Yes, I need it in Java