# Recycler view scroll to position speed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So basically I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962607/16976283) to control the speed of the scroll, but my problem is that I need the speed to be constant, and with this solution when the scroll is arriving at the end it starts to slow down.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Just override the next function without a body inside class that extend LinearSmoothScroller:

```
override fun onTargetFound(targetView: View, state: RecyclerView.State, action: Action) {

    }
```